# VLOOKUP not work

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I use this formula always for copy data from sheet2 to sheet1 with data matching condition. Normally it works fine But Why This formula not work with large text query.

Formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet2!$A:$E,COLUMN(),FALSE),"")
```

Any best formula or VBA will be  helpful for me.

Comment: Saying it "doesn't work" is not helpful information. *How* doesn't it work? What does your data look like, what is the result you expect, and what is the result you receive (if any)?

Comment: It doesn't work if text more than 256 character

Comment: Yep. That formula is perfect. I approve.

Comment: Normally it works here. But now i have a url list for matching. This URL is so large. So this formula not work.

Comment: If your look value is more than 256 characters, use Index- Match combination. For example only.  looking up A1 in E1:E10 and returning a result from F2:F10 then try this formula instead

`=INDEX(F2:F10,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(E1:E10=A1,0),0))`

change ranges as required

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when Vlookup formulas stop working when they worked in the past, it generally means that something changed in the data.  I would suggest looking at the formats of both sheets and for extra spaces or non-printable characters in the cells.

Comment: Normally it works here. But now i have a url list for  matching. This URL is so large. So this formula not work.